# Kotlin Facebook Login, logs in and skips popup

Tags: android, ios, facebook, kotlin, popup

I'm trying to add Facebook login to my Android app in Kotlin.
Background

1. Facebook login working on iOS and is LIVE for the same app in
2. Facebook The Facebook popup works fine in the simulator

When I try to login on a tethered device and click the Facebook login button, a window seems to popup quickly but then disappear quickly, and the Facebook button say Logout. No popup is displayed.

I have confirmed I am logged in, because I'm getting a valid Facebook token in console.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on what's going on?

“Works as designed” …

If a user has logged in to the app before already, and the app is not asking for any new permissions at this time - then it is simply *supposed to* work like this. (What would be the point of bothering the user with the same dialog over and over again? Especially when it doesn’t have anything *new* to ask from them this time.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have auto signin

Just Uninstall the app and delete from your trash

and Install again